# SQL Server: if else On AND Clause

Tags: if-statement, sql-server-2012

I am using the SQL Server and I am stuck with the condition where I need to run 1st `AND` clause or 2nd `AND` clause based on the `if` condition.

Please see the below query, I tried to explain my requirement. I want to run below query but in the `where` clause I have 2 `AND` conditions, whereby one will need to be ran based on `@toRun` variable, as follows;

- If `@toRun` is equal to 'first' then 1st `AND` condition should run
- Else 2nd `AND` condition will run.

Can any one help me how to do this, I have tried with both `if` and `case` but can't find a way to do it.

```
declare @toRun nvarchar(10) = 'first';
select * 
From tbl_data
where isDeleted=0

--if @toRun is equal to 'first' then following clause should run
--1st Clause:
AND FID in (select FID from t1)

--if toRun is not equal to 'first' then following clause should run
--2nd Clause:
AND TID in (select TID from t1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: adding both conditions but using the OR clause and some extra parentheses can help you run one or the other.

```
declare @toRun nvarchar(10) = 'first';
select * 
From tbl_data
where 
    isDeleted=0 AND
      (
        (@toRun = 'first' AND FID IN (SELECT FID FROM T1)) OR 
        (@ToRun != 'first' AND TID IN (SELECT TID FROM T1))
      )
```

If, in the future, you really need to use the `IF` statement to do something (and in this case, I don't really think it's necessary), your syntax would be the following:

```
declare @toRun nvarchar(10) = 'first';


IF @toRun = 'first'
  BEGIN 
    select * 
    From tbl_data
    where 
        isDeleted=0 AND
        FID IN (SELECT FID FROM T1)
  END

IF @toRun != 'first'
  BEGIN 
    select * 
    From tbl_data
    where 
        isDeleted=0 AND
        TID IN (SELECT TID FROM T1)
  END
```

Comment: cool fist example is really help full THANKS, but i didn't agree with 2nd example however its technically correct but it will make the code duplicate which i didn't want to do.

Comment: Glad it helps, @OmerAnees - if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. I do completely agree that the second option is not the method I would use myself, however I edited my original answer and included it so you could compare syntax for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is another way of doing it using `EXISTS`

```
DECLARE @ToRun nvarchar(10) = 'first';

SELECT *  
FROM tbl_data t
WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 
              WHERE (@ToRun = 'first' AND t.FID = t1.FID) OR 
                    (@ToRun <> 'first' AND t.TID = t1.TID)
             )
```